# How do i get data from the API(when i use map i get TypeError: userdata.map is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I need help to display the data from the API.
When i try to get the data with map i get an error. TypeError: userdata.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export class HighscoreList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://schnitzeljagdar.herokuapp.com/users/getAllUser")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>User</h2>
        {this.state.users}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use a single magic quote to format this "TypeError: userdata.map is not a function" into this: `TypeError: userdata.map is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cherry-63ee9

```
export default class HighscoreList extends React.Component {
    state = {
      users: []
    };

  componentDidMount() {
      axios
      .get("https://schnitzeljagdar.herokuapp.com/users/getAllUser")
      .then(res => this.setState({users:[res.data]}))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {users} = this.state;
    let array = users[0]?Object.values(users[0]):[];
    console.log(array)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
         {array.map((arr,index)=>
          <div key={index}>
          <h2>{arr.username}</h2>
          <p>{arr.email}</p>
          </div>
          )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```